# Android - Call application share intent from the outside

Tags: android, android-intent

Let's say application A can share it's content, and applications B and C registered to that shared intent.
Can another application (D) call automatically A->share operation without the user pressing the "share" button in application A?

For example: Can I implement an application that will call gallery share (in case gallery is open now and an image is currently displayed) from the outside?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

imho not without modifying application A